# How to Set Text Format by User-Defined Function with Input as String

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation, text-formatting

I have simple but annoying problem here. I guess it occurs to many Mathematica users.

The thing is that I wish to define a function to format the text in Mathematica. Yet, I don't know whether it is possible.

Say if I want to make a plot with FrameLabel set, like the following script:

```
Show[
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.8,
 FrameLabel -> {Style[ToExpression["x", TeXForm, HoldForm], 18,FontFamily -> Times, Bold], 
 Style[ToExpression["x^2", TeXForm, HoldForm], 18, FontFamily -> Times, Bold]},
 RotateLabel -> False
 ]
```

which generate this plot

[image]

The thing is I have type this bothering format setting script again and again if I need to plot a lot, though the format I set every time is the very same.

```
Style[ToExpression["x^2", TeXForm, HoldForm], 18, FontFamily -> Times, Bold]}
```

Therefore, I am wondering if I can define a function to overpass such prolix script. For example,

```
SetStyle[input_] := Style[ToExpression[ToString[input, InputForm], TeXForm, HoldForm],18,FontFamily -> Times];
```

It works for superscript, but it fail in the most of the Latex input, like **\\theta** or **\\frac{x}{2}** and even just the subscript like **x_0**

anyone know how I can fix my code?

Thanks for your kind and generous suggestion.

Comment: Have you see the [MaTeX paclet](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)?

Comment: One way is to define a function like `st[txt_String] := 
  Style[ToExpression[txt, TeXForm, HoldForm], 18, FontFamily -> Times, Bold]` and then the option `FrameLabel` look as follows: `FrameLabel -> {st["x"], st["x^2"]}`.

Comment: @LukasLang Yap, i tried it before. I'm not sure whether i did it wrong, i experienced some problems when installing. Yet, I believe MaTex the first option of most of users. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Amazing! it is the solution i am looking for. This is really clever! I did not know such input argument until you show it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would like to give this credit to [Alexei Boulbitch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/788/alexei-boulbitch). He made a little but critical amend in the input argument of my original code.

The function should be defined as following , instead,

```
st[txt_String] := Style[ToExpression[txt, TeXForm, HoldForm], 18, FontFamily -> Times, Bold]
```

In this way, the input of the function could be a string and the problem mentioned above could be perfectly solved!

For example, one can set the FrameLabel like given by Alexei

```
FrameLabel -> {st["x"], st["x^2"]}
```

It works even for a complicate LaTeX input, for example,

```
FrameLabel -> {st["\\frac{x}{C}"], st["\\phi_0+\\theta_1"]}
```

Once again, thank you @AlexeiBoulbitch